# Trackpoint left mouse clicks sent as two clicks

Tags: xubuntu, mouse, thinkpad, trackpoint

I have installed Xubuntu 23.04 on a ThinkPad X1 Carbon. Generally it works well.

However, on some apps (it appears worse on some than others) when I click the left physical ('TrackPoint'?) mouse button it registers two button clicks in the app I'm using.

Tapping the left side of the touchpad appears to work fine - one button press is registered.

I have tried:

```
xev | grep ButtonRelease
```

And I've confirmed only one ButtonRelease event occurs for each click on both the touch pad and the physical trackpoint buttons.